# Heroku does not look for the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE I've set for it

Tags: django, heroku

I'm deploying my first site. I intend to use one settings file for production and one for development. Thus I have this structure:

```
workout
|
|-\settings
    |
    |- production.py
    |- development.py
```

In order to let heroku know where to find the settings file, I do this:

```
$ heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=workout.settings.production
Setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and restarting ⬢ workoutcalendar... done, v3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: workout.settings.production
```

And push again. Everything should be fine now, right? But no:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'workout.settings'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to workoutcalendar.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/workoutcalendar.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/workoutcalendar.git'
```

It seems like it's looking for workout.settings instead of workout.settings.production, right? Why does it do that when I've set the environment variable for it the same way I've done on my private machine (where it works)?